# .htaccess forcing error pages on SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following piece of code in my .htaccess file to force redirecting to custom error pages:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorPages/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorPages/403.php
ErrorDocument 400 /ErrorPages/generalError.php
ErrorDocument 401 /ErrorPages/generalError.php
ErrorDocument 500 /ErrorPages/generalError.php
```

Everything works fine on port 80, but when it comes to SSL, the standard error pages are shown.

To be more specific:

http:www.mydomain.com/NoExistingPage.php redirects to the custom error page
https:www.mydomain.com/NoExistingPage.php **DOES NOT** redirect to the custom error page

am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a separate directory that holds your secure stuff or is it the same directory?

Comment: Yes, there is the /secured folder with all the must-be-SSL pages on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a duplicate .htaccess file in the /secured folder and see if that works. The vhost for the https daemon is probably using /secured as doc_root which means even if the .htaccess from the regular doc_root is below the secured folder it will be ignored.

Comment: sorry for the delay! I was at work and forgot to check back :)