# Custom 404 error redirect not working for https requests in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, apache2, errordocument

I have a simple 404 redirect in a .htaccess file which works fine for Http requests:-

```
ErrorDocument 404 /apps/handle_error.php
```

The handle_error.php returns an appropriate PNG image depending on the URL path. However, when I replace the request with Https, it returns the default 404 error page and never does the redirect.

I know my SSL certificate is installed correctly as I get valid content returned for normal static pages. Is there something I am missing in my htaccess file regarding 404 error redirects  for Https requests?

(A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770612/htaccess-forcing-error-pages-on-ssl) but with no clear resolution)

Answer (score 2):

After much soul searching I found the answer, for my specific case anyway.
My Apache2, mod_ssl and mod_rewrite was not configured correctly to work together. The default  AllowOverride setting in my SSL config was set to "None" and mod_rewrite requires a minimum of  AllowOverride of "FileInfo".

(To be fair, I got my answer from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/226908/why-do-htaccess-redirects-work-in-http-but-not-with-https))